# Neo4j Wildfly OGM . Works fine in local unit tests but fails after deploying with resource exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, neo4j, wildfly, neo4j-ogm

My project structure is

- ear

  - server.war
  - lib/persistence.jar
  - META-INF/application.xml

I have `neo4j-ogm` related code in `persistence jar`. And my dependencies are

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have a `User` entity in package `com.abcd.persistence.nodes`
And in `UserDAO` i am trying to add a user like this

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Manju");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("com.abcd.persistence.nodes");
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

This `works fine` if i run the test case in the `persistence.jar`. But it fails when i try to access after deployment using REST services those are defined in `Server.war`

Stacktrace is

```
Exception handling request to /ws/test: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Resource: vfs:/content/ear.ear/lib/persistence.jar/com/abcd/persistence/nodes/
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:168)
```

And

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Resource: vfs:/content/ear.ear/lib/persistence.jar/com/abcd/persistence/nodes/
at org.neo4j.ogm.ClassUtils.getUniqueClasspathElements(ClassUtils.java:135)
at org.neo4j.ogm.scanner.ClassPathScanner.getUniqueClasspathElements(ClassPathScanner.java:158)
at org.neo4j.ogm.scanner.ClassPathScanner.scan(ClassPathScanner.java:130)
at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo.load(DomainInfo.java:260)
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

It reads like it can't connect to the service endpoint. Download SoapUI and see if you can get the REST service to work.

Soapui.org

Comment: It works fine when i call neo4j rest url using curl. And i am already mentioned that test case works fine. It is not able to resolve the entity package at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The OGM needs a plugin to support Wildfly (due to the vfs protocol).

You need to implement the `org.neo4j.ogm.classloader.ResourceResolver` interface and handle the resource accordingly (see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/48#issuecomment-190288304)

But,there's an implementation [already available](https://github.com/ctpconsulting/neo4j-ogm-resourceresolver-vfs) so you can just use this one.